# My prefix is a sneaky ad, My suffix is not yet closed

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix is a sneaky ad.
>
> My suffix isn't yet closed.
>
> My infix does sound rad.
>
> My whole is evil and cold.

Comment: Can you add a hint? I have thought of several options for "sneaky ad" but it's difficult to narrow with the current clues.  I could be on entirely the wrong track :)

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> demon?

My prefix is a sneaky ad

> In marketing, a product demonstration (or "**demo**" for short) is a promotion where a product is demonstrated to potential customers.
> A game demo version could also be considered an ad.

My suffix isn't yet closed

> It's **on**, meaning not off or closed

My infix does sound rad

> Not sure about that, maybe emo just sounds cool and OP likes the 2000s? :)

My whole is evil and cold

> A demon is arguably evil, and 'cold' in the sense of lack of emotion, friendliness, or compassion

Comment: Do you mean [emo](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=Dictionary&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONQesSoyi3w8sc9YSmZSWtOXmMU4-LzL0jNc8lMLsnMz0ssqrRiUWJKzeNZxMqFEAMA7_QXqzcAAAA&zx=1599688544878#dobs=emo) as in [emo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emo)?